# put rows of numbers into a column with shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file with many lines, like

```
1 jfkdajfd   1 2 3 5
2 fkldfjld   
3 fdkfloaf   9 10
4 fldfldkf 
5 fdskf;ak   12 1 4
```

I want to get all the numbers and put them in a column in a file, like

```
 1
 2
 3
 5
 9
 10
 12
 1
 4
```

how can I achieve this?
thanks

Comment: Are you actually looking for numbers or to limit the output to consecutive digits (i.e. positive integers)?  For a more specific example, do you want `123.456` to show up as 1 decimal number or 2 integers or not at all?

Comment: It seems you are doing some exercises because you have asked a series of these questions today. And this question seems to serve no practical purpose with your description. Why not try to figure them out by youself first if necessary.

Comment: Also asked [on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13419948/7552)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i + 0 == $i) print $i }' < input > output
```

I use `x + 0 == x` as the test to see if `x` is a valid `awk` number, then print the original string.  It's up to you to decide if you want `awk` numbers (this includes floating point, negative numbers, and on many implementations, hexadecimal numbers as well), or something different.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
tr -cs 0-9 '[\n*]' < input | grep . > output
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the point of the `grep .`?

Comment: @jw013, removing the leading empty line if the first character of "input" is not a digit.